# Formula for this sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

what's the formula for the sequence

7, 11, 7, 11, 7, 11

What type of sequence is this?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$a_n=9+2\cdot(-1)^n\ \ (n=1,2,\cdots).$$

Comment: This sequence appears in some interesting context. Search OEIS. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 1):

The most trivial answer is that. Suppose, that the first index of the sequence is $1$, then
$$a_n = \begin{cases}  7, & \mbox{if } n \mbox{ odd} \\  11,  & \mbox{if } n \mbox{ even} \end{cases}$$
You could also find other exotic solutions at [*OEIS*](http://oeis.org/search?q=7%2C11%2C7%2C11%2C7%2C11).